# Redirect all http and https subdomains to other subdomain

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

**I'm trying to redirect:**

- minecloud.domain.co
- https//minecloud.domain.co
- beta.minecloud.domain.co

**To:**

- https//beta.minecloud.domain.co

Here is my code, but it doesn't redirect https//minecloud.domain.co to what I want:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^beta.minecloud\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://beta.minecloud.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302]
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
# Redirect http://beta.minecloud.domain.co/ to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^beta\.minecloud\.domain\.co$
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302]
# Redirect minecloud.domain.co to beta.minecloud.domain.co
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^minecloud\.domain\.co$
RewriteRule ^ https://beta.minecloud.domain.co%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302]
```

Are you sure you want 302 redirects? 301 permanent redirects may be better for you, although these 302's are better for testing.

The extra `RewriteCond` on line 3 is necessary to avoid a double redirect for `http://minecloud.domain.co`.